# Smooth Scrolling anchor with offset (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, anchor-scroll

Im using the following code to add smooth scrolling for anchors on my site.
Because i have a sticky header id like to offset this by say 200px

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try add or remove a value in the scrollTop animation

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    var offset = -200; // <-- change the value here
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top + offset
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This solution works nicely, but it does not change the URL to #anchor. So the user cannot link directly to the url with anchor.

Answer (score 4):

A simpler example with no hash is:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top + -200
    }, 1000);
});
```